# Can't find view in subfolder

Tags: java, scala, web-applications, playframework-2.0

I just started using the Play2.0 Framework and I'm trying to use the main template in my `home/index` template. The issue I'm having is it can't find "main" when its in the Shared folder, if I take it out and put it in the Views root then it works fine.

So I'm wondering how I can reference the `main.scala.html` from `index.scala.html`?

My folder structure is as follows:

- Views

  - Home

    - index.scala.html
  - Shared

    - main.scala.html

My code in `index.scala.html` is:

```
@head = {

}

@content = {
    <b>Home Screen</b>!!
}

ERROR: @main(title = "Home",head, content)
```

The error I get is:

```
not found: value main.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get into subfolders for views there is this like "pseudo-package" called "html". I'm not entire sure how it works but try this:

```
@views.html.Shared.main
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
@Shared.main(title = "Home",head, content)
```

For security and performance reasons Play compiles templates to Scala functions and stores it in managed folder `/target/scala-2.9.1/src_managed/main/views`, so you can preview it to find correct path.

rules are easy for view files saved with pattern:

- `/app/views/viewName.scala.ext` (where `ext` can be `html`, `xml` or `txt`) Play will compile views to: `view.ext.viewName`
- and for `/app/views/SomeSub/OtherSub/viewName.scala.ext` it will be: `view.ext.SomeSub.OtherSub.viewName`

so:

```
/app/views/general.scala.html             = views.html.general
/app/views/Main/index.scala.html          = views.html.Main.index
/app/views/Api/usersList.scala.xml        = views.xml.Api.usersList
/app/views/Email/English/body.scala.txt   = views.txt.Email.English.body
```

etc...

There is some case with `/app/views/tags` package which is auto imported to the views, so you can  use `/app/views/tags/myTag.scala.html` just with: `@tags.myTag(args)` syntax in any view.

Comment: Ah, I've never output anything other than html from my scala views but that makes perfect sense now. Good to know, and a more complete answer than what I gave.

Comment: Note that this has moved to `target\scala-2.11\classes_managed\views\html` in Play 2.3.2.