# Handling multiple template files with playframework in complex application?

Tags: scala, templates, playframework

I recently found out that Scala is an absolutely interesting programming language.
Since I'm not a real desktop application developer but more a webdeveloper I wanted to try out the play framework and if it works well for my purposes.

So far, I really like it, it seems to be easy to use and the developers really think it through.

BUT
I wanted to create an application with different templates, like an "internal", "external" and "admin" area. I already figured out to try out the "modular application" thing which seems to work good but I can't see any possibility to create something like multiple "template" files..
After a few hours of googling, I thought I should just ask..

Has anybody of you done it yet? Any tips how to organise it the best way?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you provide a small code example of how you would use it?

Comment: What is that mean'multiple template files' ?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would use it, I would guess something like this:

For an external page like the "contact" page:
@external() {
  <h1>Contact</h1>
}

For an internal page like that:
@internal() {
  <h1>Welcome to the internal area</h1>
}


I'm not sure how many "templates" I will need in the future but there might be a lot so I want them organized in an own folder or like that.

So multiple template files: Just a lot of files that provide different "standard HTML structures"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have as many `views` as required and you can also organize them in packages (under the `app.views` package) in many levels. All you need is just to learn how to reference required view from the controller.

Take a look to this [sample schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14625097/1066240).

In other words the most importantis clear and comfortable **for you** order, which **you** will be able to work with after 3 years without additional notes.