# How to render a simple HTML page in Playframework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have added a simple Login page in this directory

> C:\play-2.2.2\samples\java\forms\app\views\Ecal_Login\login.html

The same page when moved to this directory works fine

> C:\play-2.2.2\samples\java\forms\app\views

I want to render the same page from views\Ecal_login directory. How can I do that?

I am using this function

> ```
>  public static Result login()
>    {
>         return ok(login.render());
>    }
> ```
>
> Note:I have this page as login.html and not login.scala.html just for the record!

Comment: Do you use some other templating language in your template than Play's default template engine (since it looks like you want to avoid the `.scala.html` suffix)?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea of other templating language. I can work with .scala as well but my concern is to render the page from views.Ecal_login directory.. thanks :)

Comment: Okay, great. If you name your templates `*.scala.html`, then everything in your views folder and its subdirectories will be compiled, and available as methods in respective sub-packages. In your case, you should be able to write `return ok(Ecal_Login.render());`. I'll check later.

Comment: I renamed the file as login.scala.html  restarted and compiled..and now it is in this directory C:\play-2.2.2\samples\java\forms\app\views\Ecal_Login\login.scala.html and I am using this code ok(views.Ecal_Login.render()). the prediction doesn't give render option.

Comment: It would be `ok(views.html.Ecal_Login.login.render())`.

Comment: @estmatic Yeah, right, sorry, that's what i meant *whistles innocently*

Answer (score 1):

As **estmatic** already commented it should be

```
ok(views.html.Ecal_Login.login.render())
```

Here you'll find several other samples for working with views in subpackages:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14625097/1066240